# How to implement push notifications on my android device

Tags: java, android, postgresql, rest, google-cloud-messaging

I have a very basic design of my entire application, where several users with my app on there android devices commits data to the server (I have used REST web services(java) + postgresql as my server) through HTTP post request from the android application. I am successful in achieving this and app runs absolutely fine. Now i want to implement a scenario where any change(CRUD operations) on my db on server should create a notification on my users android device. How should i achieve this with my server design unchanged? I have looked into Google Cloud Messaging, but could figure out the server implementation.

For now i have implemented db triggers on postgresql and able to get control back into java code using Notify/Listen feature of postgresql. From here i need to connect to android device. How can this be achieved. Is Google Cloud Messaging the only way? I have not seen any insert/update statements in there server implementation. Could anyone please guide me on this?

Answer (score 4):

either you can use GCM or implement a Socket at server end and open a socket connection from mobile but this approach may add some additional processing overhead because it will create a daemon thread to listen socket port from mobile device.

Answer (score 2):

You should use native library (**NotificationManager** etc.), [here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidNotifications/article.html) you can find a great tutorial.

Comment: This comes much latter into picture after you are able to send response from server to android, which i am not able to resolve.

Comment: Do you understand what is push notification? The question is about push notifications and not about how the notifications to be displayed on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

My Advice is for you to use GCM.  GCM normally takes a maximum of 4kb, so you could have your own defined "commands". You could use them to determine the requests on both ends, ie on android app and the server end. A php script on the server would help you in this.

I am working on an app where by the android app sends messages to the server via POST and the server forwards the message to the appropriate user via GCM. In my case I have very many things to share so in that case I am using commands, for example if it is a new incoming message I send a GCM to the app with one variable as the command and the rest as the data. On the android app I use the command variable to determine what to do with the data.

Kindly avoid that socket advice, it will have your app drain the battery to sustain the open socket ,  besides you don't have to re-invent the wheel while Google servers already has it

Comment: Are you using any db at backend?

Comment: For using GCM, do we need to have a db at all or not??

Comment: Yes I am. I am using mysql on the server end.  But you don't have to connect to db directly obviously so you will need a php or any other server side script to handle the requests, to the db